# Does Islam has an explanation of why people die of hunger?

Tags: quran

I am a Muslim and I keep hearing from people that rizq(what a person would eat) is promised by God and will be given and one has to focus on following religion rather than worrying too much about where money will come from. This made me think why people die of hunger? What explanation does religion has for it?

Comment: Rizq and what you will eat are two different matters and not necessarily the same.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Can you please explain this further as an answer?

Comment: Rizq means provision and can be interpreted to whatever helps to get provision like health, money etc. So getting rizq doesn't mean getting food because you may waste it... also the fact that Allah gives provision is only one part of the medal as Allah is the giving and the taking!

Answer (score 2):

Explanation is simple. Death is predestined. Those people are destined to die at that time by that method. Their Rizq beyond their fixed life was not ordained.

This does not mean that they should not exert effort to earn their Rizq. Prophet Yusuf in Egypt told them to take advantage of 7 years of abundance and to store grain to withstand the 7 years of famine, he didn't tell them to go to sleep and let Allah worry about their Rizq.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and chccking our [help]. This post would profit from evidences that support your claims! Also read [answer].